# How iPhone application WeatherTunes realized running in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, daemon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Switch music from my app to the ipod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7993236/how-to-switch-music-from-my-app-to-the-ipod)

There is an iPhone application named WeatherTunes (天气旋律闹钟 in Chinese) in iPhone AppStor, search with key words "WeatherTunes " e, it appears at the first. 
You can add alarm in WeatherTunes, even if you switch this application to background, it still runs. I look into its info.plist file, I noticed it set the "required background modes" with value "App plays audio". But I still can't figure out how it can be run in background? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Apps can run in the background if they have any of the 5 requirements:

- Apps that play audio while in the Background state. A good example is Instacast while it’s playing a podcast.
- Apps that track your location in the background. For example, you still want voice prompts from your turn-by-turn GPS navigation app, even if another app is Active.
- Apps that listen for incoming voice-over-IP (VOIP) calls. If you use Skype on iOS, you can receive incoming Skype calls while the app is in the background.
- Newsstand apps that are downloading new content.
- Apps that receive continuous updates from an external accessory in the background.

It may be possible that this app is playing a silent audio file in the background, a tactic that I have seen before, but generally that will be rejected from the apple store.

Comment: Just as you said, the only way I can think of is playing a silent audio in the background. However, the ine hand,if it continues playing a silent audio, I am not sure whether it will consume much battery or not, the other hand, how this application past applestore's verification.